# ListItem css change on active page

Tags: jquery, css, menu

I've tried a few ways  to accomplish this and none seem to work for me.

I have a fairly simple menu at the top of my page with links, which are, by default, font-weight of normal and color grey, and hovering over them turns them bold and white.
This works fine, but what I want is for the current page menu item to be bold and white.
e.g. If I'm on the Home page, I want the Home Link to be bold and white while the others are grey and normal, and if I go to the About page, the About Link is bold and white while the others are grey and normal.

Currently I have this:

html:

```
<ul id="menuListItems" class="headerMenu"> 
        <li id="home"><a href="./Home.php">Home</a></li> 
        <li id="about"><a href="./About.php">About Me</a></li> 
        <li id="services"><a href="./Services.php">Services</a></li> 
        <li id="gallery"><a href="./Gallery.php">Gallery</a></li> 
        <li id="contact"><a href="./Contact.php">Contact Me</a></li>
</ul>
```

The 'headerMenu' Class just styles the list.

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $("#menuListItems li").each(function() {            
        if (document.URL.toUpperCase().indexOf($(this).attr('id').toUpperCase()) > -1) 
        {
            $(this).addClass("isSelected");
        }
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.isSelected a { font-weight: bold; color:white;}
```

The above is not working, now the weird thing is, I can't even manually set the `<li>` class to 'isSelected' e.g. `<li id="home" class="isSelected"><a href="./Home.php">Home</a></li>`. This is something I would have expected to have worked, so it would seem that the class attribute is not being set properly for the `<li>`.

Anyone have any ideas why this is not working? Or in fact another way that can achieve what i need?

Many Thanks

EDIT:

Here is the remaining CSS that is required:

```
ul.headerMenu { 
    list-style:none; /* remove bullets */ 
    padding-left: 50px;
    width: 630px;
    top: 303px;
    position: absolute;
} 

ul.headerMenu li a { 
    padding:10px 20px; 
    text-decoration:none; 
    float:left; 
    font: 15px "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal; 
    color: grey;
} 
ul.headerMenu li a:hover 
{ 
    color:white; 
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Ive also made a slight change to the orginial code to not use the else block to set isNotSelected and just added this to `ul.headerMenu li a`

Comment: I generally set an "active" class (like your "isSelected") to the current page's nav link server-side, rather than after the page is loaded. That might be an easier solution for you, if you're using PHP or something. Otherwise, I'd still suggest just making the default style for the links the "isNotSelected," and then only setting an "isSelected" which would override those styles.

Comment: Can you post a link and/or a jsfiddle and/or all of the relevant CSS? I am guessing their is a conflict in the CSS.

Comment: Maybe the class is applied to early and is getting wiped by other styles? A JSFiddle re-creating the issue might help.

Comment: Works for me - jsfiddle.net/8DPsv Based on your saying you can't even add it manually, my guess is you have a JavaScript error elsewhere that is preventing this code from ever running.

Comment: Thanks Guys, I've updated the first post with more CSS which effects the menu, and also change the code slightly to not use isNotSelected. As far as I can see, there are no conflicts in the CSS, I have no other javascript on the page. @jblasco How would I do this server side with php? any examples will be a great help.

Comment: It sounds like your selected styling is getting overwritten by a more specific selector (or one that's equally specific but further down in your code). Shouldn't be too hard to figure out though using something like Firebug. I'd recommend, though, _not_ to use a class to denote a menu item as being selected but rather wrap the `a` element in a `strong` element which would also semantically make it "selected".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in conjunction with your javascript that adds the class.

```
ul.headerMenu li.isSelected a { 
    font-weight: bold; 
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The styles for the link are probably overriding the styles that are being applied by the class. Try this instead

```
.isSelected a { font-weight: bold; color:white;}
#menuListItems  li a { font-weight: normal; color: grey;}
```

And there's no need for `IsNotSelected` as this will be the default style.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work either, Ive updated my code (and first post) to not use isNotSelected and use the above, but it still doesn't work

Comment: Well, this wouldn't work as `#menuListItems  li a` has a much higher specificity than `.isSelected a`. Include the ID and li in the .isSelected selector as well and you should be good.

Comment: @powerbuoy, thanks, you are also correct, I had to add the ID and li to the .isSelected to give it higher specificity, as Scott had also mentioned (which I accepted as the answer)